# PathTransition is not working as I thought it should (confusion on using CubicCurveTo/ArcTo and coordinates in general)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making the prototype of a game I'm trying to make with JavaFX. It requires a character/sprite to move in a curved path forward (basically jump to a specific position forward). I tried using MoveTo (using the layoutX and layoutY values of the ImageView of the sprite, hard-coded) with CubicCurveTo and ArcTo to specify this path, but then, the sprite jumps and starts the animation from way past below the window and just performs the animation starting from that point, even though my sprite is around the middle of the window.

I tried setting the MoveTo to 0, but then the sprite jumps to a slightly different position near its current position (upper left side of the sprite), and then performs the animation still up to past below the window. As of what I can understand, the CubicCurveTo and ArcTo final coordinates were still the same no matter where the MoveTo is located.

My general question is, how does the coordinate systems of these path elements work? Specifically, how do  I make my sprite move in a curved position forward without it jumping past below the window?

Here's my code (This is inside the initialize() method of the controller class of my FXML):

```
/*
The root is a Pane with prefWidth = 960, prefHeight = 540
*/
public void initialize() {
    /*
    char1 is the ImageView of the sprite. layoutX = 270, layoutY = 290
    */
    char1.setScaleX(-1);

    final Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 0));
    // these are rough numbers, based on the coordinate system that the layoutX and layoutY of the ImageView uses
    // path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(300, 200, 400, 200, 500, 290));
    path.getElements().add(new ArcTo(100, 60, 40, 500, 290, true, true));

    final PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
    pathTransition.setNode(char1);
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(1);
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

    jumpButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            pathTransition.play();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So uhm, I solved my own problem (?). I found out that these PathElements use coordinates that are **relative** to the current position of the Node, and that the transforms are based off on the **center** of the Node. So for my sprite to jump forward, my CubicCurveTo needed to have negative y-coordinates on the two control points. As for the part where my sprite jumps because of it centered on the specified point (because ImageView coordinate values refer to their origin, i.e. the upper left corner of the bounding box, if I'm not wrong), I'll have to work around that for now. At least I got the biggest problem out.

I'm wondering, though, if there is any documentation saying that PathElements using the relative position of the Node to move it around.